# how to get useful data from xhr responses in facebook page?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to web scrape my facebook page to get the birthdays of all my friends. Since facebook uses ajax calls to load the friends names in the "birthday events" page, i looked in the network activity in chrome dev tools to figure out where and how its doing the xhr calls and how the response data is .

The response from these calls , don't mean anything to me . They're looking like they're obfuscated or something... How to extract the data that I see on the site using the response data I get when the xhr calls are made ?

here is the response data :

```
for (;;); {
    "__ar": 1,
    "payload": null,
    "domops": [
        ["replace", "#birthdays_pager", false, {
            "__html": "\u003Cdiv class=\"_4-u2 _tzh _fbBirthdays__monthCard _4-u8\">\u003Cdiv class=\"_4-u3 _5dwa _5dw9\" id=\"birthdays_monthly_card_1522566000\">\u003Cspan class=\"_38my\">April\u003Cspan class=\"_c1c\">\u003C\/span>\u003C\/span>\u003Cspan class=\"_5dw8\">\u003Cdiv class=\"_tzj\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/kajal.chaudhary.5492\">Kajal Chaudhary\u003C\/a>, \u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/shreesha.bhat.963\">Shreesha Bhat Galimane\u003C\/a> and 19 others\u003C\/div>\u003C\/span>\u003Cdiv class=\"_3s3-\">\u003C\/div>\u003C\/div>\u003Cdiv class=\"_4-u3\">\u003Cdiv class=\"_43qm _tzu _43q9\">\u003Cul class=\"uiList _4cg3 _509- _4ki\">\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/satish.ven.58\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Satish Ven (4\/2)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/27540391_2084438825122967_6451048031944951645_n.jpg?oh=77383450a07722e1a44bf39c6d2c12f7&amp;oe=5B19517E\" alt=\"Satish Ven\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/sheshufirefox\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Sheshadri Sharma (4\/6)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/16998890_758118407695665_4675113951836594565_n.jpg?oh=946ce323c5b3824fbf8dbbe59fd9160f&amp;oe=5B02616B\" alt=\"Sheshadri Sharma\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/aayush.sinha.146\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Aayush Sinha (4\/8)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/10968514_981734045189455_1830626709337028270_n.jpg?oh=428a495a9379b6b2202408aa5284923b&amp;oe=5B12711E\" alt=\"Aayush Sinha\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/pranav.ys.5\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Pranav YS (4\/11)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/12541116_1676590859264773_7240167064125691378_n.jpg?oh=3d4d0b034a06ecf460b8668fcdd0fad2&amp;oe=5AD7EEAA\" alt=\"Pranav YS\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/profile.php?id=100012822522252\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Pankaj Thakur (4\/11)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/27752205_468390053598408_3401567454276318428_n.jpg?oh=1f2fb7ee2da724506757029fdb8a46b2&amp;oe=5B1F151B\" alt=\"Pankaj Thakur\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/prajwal.bhadravathiravi\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Prajwal Bhadravathi Ravi (4\/11)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/c10.0.57.57\/p57x57\/26000914_361577560980364_1712446738221265545_n.jpg?oh=370dc4419b0767b7e79bc27e854bc06b&amp;oe=5B03D96B\" alt=\"Prajwal Bhadravathi Ravi\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/sachinr.doddaguni\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Sachin R Doddaguni (4\/12)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/c17.0.57.57\/p57x57\/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=21091066fea75337ac98a3cf1f341740&amp;oe=5B16DBF3\" alt=\"Sachin R Doddaguni\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/kajal.chaudhary.5492\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Kajal Chaudhary (4\/14)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/23316350_1440015076106508_6579302328578807067_n.jpg?oh=4e3fc491c9a32f9581286452933b1e50&amp;oe=5B227D7E\" alt=\"Kajal Chaudhary\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/usha.shastri.54\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Usha Shastri (4\/14)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/c0.0.57.57\/p57x57\/10152373_10203424125546031_1766227792_n.jpg?oh=8b0e95a8a60e09c79005a84f3c6a8b98&amp;oe=5B225FD5\" alt=\"Usha Shastri\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/ashish.dwivedi.39566\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Ashish Dwivedi (4\/14)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/26239697_2005584583047675_396510917460842524_n.jpg?oh=eab2bd118623e449e2dcefa3fb64899e&amp;oe=5B021392\" alt=\"Ashish Dwivedi\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/shreesha.bhat.963\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Shreesha Bhat Galimane (4\/15)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/27541088_2089364294633310_7146912677909552069_n.jpg?oh=e16a6a514982d8f15ae0a1c81a719752&amp;oe=5B1B0577\" alt=\"Shreesha Bhat Galimane\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/chethanhr.chazz\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Chethan Vilas (4\/16)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/13620256_595294770631304_6000009159215075898_n.jpg?oh=b5b3ea3db6040e8a79233a7e90c916a9&amp;oe=5B1C56BD\" alt=\"Chethan Vilas\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/kshitija.kallesh\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Kshitija Vidya Kallesh (4\/18)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/26733802_1408840822577029_120794789359415364_n.jpg?oh=19b7eada0711726990750fb6cf4add09&amp;oe=5B03C8E7\" alt=\"Kshitija Vidya Kallesh\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/vishesh.ug\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Vishesh Umesh Gujjar (4\/18)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/21192739_1939744576303216_5388844998198614270_n.jpg?oh=24d78a736265c7c8c0adeb54324f5894&amp;oe=5B08520E\" alt=\"Vishesh Umesh Gujjar\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/santosh.bhat.7359\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Santosh Bhat (4\/18)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/19149245_1892258634388875_8828676164364322774_n.jpg?oh=741b3bf6f9080726d54251044ba34355&amp;oe=5B09B6F5\" alt=\"Santosh Bhat\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/profile.php?id=100007305601325\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Rahul Kumar (4\/20)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/c90.210.540.540\/s57x57\/21685964_1884540188466150_8711746607997503911_n.jpg?oh=09c4c1f9f707950987c0eb70e7f3ad58&amp;oe=5B1329B8\" alt=\"Rahul Kumar\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/sumantha.murali\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Sumanth Sharma (4\/22)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/c1.0.57.57\/p57x57\/20663860_764480790380420_5549902384541679375_n.jpg?oh=132d2d9ec2b0b1f77f83620fc1efeb2a&amp;oe=5B044E32\" alt=\"Sumanth Sharma\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/archana.kashyap.90226\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Sweekruthi Kashyap (4\/22)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/26814579_2066880066876357_3732840647672074955_n.jpg?oh=e27797ae7d2fcfa8ca23cf06bc36dbb9&amp;oe=5B081963\" alt=\"Sweekruthi Kashyap\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/vinayaka.cbg\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Vinayaka Bhat Galimane (4\/23)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/25994873_1536622213073481_4403814656121225467_n.jpg?oh=d26a01066699d858d20bfa367fba02a4&amp;oe=5B0EC392\" alt=\"Vinayaka Bhat Galimane\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/profile.php?id=100004456147835\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Pruthvi Kalyan Reddy (4\/28)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/14563438_693932530765279_8227735103682834751_n.jpg?oh=17a9ef5cfa963fe9902bc16e94e6b51d&amp;oe=5B0F7604\" alt=\"Pruthvi Kalyan Reddy\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003Cli class=\"_43q7\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/kushal.kushu.31\" class=\"link\" data-jsid=\"anchor\" data-hover=\"tooltip\" data-tooltip-content=\"Kushal Kushu (4\/29)\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _ry img\" src=\"https:\/\/scontent.fblr6-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p57x57\/19366450_1032761963526766_3567943503656629473_n.jpg?oh=cdf7c11db05db93d8fd0e966d816ea98&amp;oe=5B1B0A36\" alt=\"Kushal Kushu\" data-jsid=\"img\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003C\/li>\u003C\/ul>\u003C\/div>\u003C\/div>\u003C\/div>\u003Cdiv class=\"clearfix uiMorePager stat_elem _52jv\" id=\"birthdays_pager\">\u003Cdiv>\u003Ca rel=\"ajaxify\" href=\"\/async\/birthdays\/?date=1525158000\" class=\"pam uiBoxLightblue uiMorePagerPrimary\">May\u003Ci class=\"mhs mts arrow img sp_m7lN5cdLBIi sx_fa6ba6\">\u003C\/i>\u003C\/a>\u003Cspan class=\"uiMorePagerLoader pam uiBoxLightblue\">\u003Cimg class=\"img\" src=\"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/yb\/r\/GsNJNwuI-UM.gif\" alt=\"\" width=\"16\" height=\"11\" \/>\u003C\/span>\u003C\/div>\u003C\/div>"
        }]
    ],
    "jsmods": {
        "instances": [
            ["__inst_1c03405d_i_0", ["MorePagerFetchOnScroll", "__elem_1c03405d_i_0"],
                [{
                    "__m": "__elem_1c03405d_i_0"
                }, 0, true], 1
            ]
        ],
        "elements": [
            ["__elem_1c03405d_i_0", "birthdays_pager", 1]
        ],
        "require": [
            ["__inst_1c03405d_i_0"],
            ["Tooltip"]
        ]
    },
    "js": ["lbOvC", "I1Wyg", "iaXyh", "RIWAf"],
    "css": ["trv4T", "eyM74", "0wVzo", "YGsVX", "rwXTv", "hAqW4", "bTiWO"],
    "bootloadable": {
        "TimeSliceInteractionsLiteTypedLogger": {
            "resources": ["ZN6iu", "lbOvC", "trv4T"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "WebSpeedInteractionsTypedLogger": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC", "lTQVw", "trv4T"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "AsyncDOM": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC", "trv4T", "d25Q1"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "Dialog": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC", "YGsVX", "trv4T"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "ErrorSignal": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC", "trv4T", "eVg16", "CHoRV"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "ExceptionDialog": {
            "resources": ["vdrq6", "lbOvC", "JeUwF", "YGsVX", "trv4T", "mzeym", "eVg16", "taIOX", "iaXyh"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "PageTransitions": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC", "np5Vl", "trv4T", "eVg16", "I1Wyg", "iaXyh"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "ReactDOM": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC", "trv4T"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "QuickSandSolver": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC", "Klc20", "trv4T", "+ClWy", "6Q\/Yd"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "ConfirmationDialog": {
            "resources": ["oE4Do", "lbOvC", "trv4T"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "Banzai": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC", "trv4T"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "BanzaiODS": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC", "trv4T"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "ResourceTimingBootloaderHelper": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC", "CHoRV"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "TimeSliceHelper": {
            "resources": ["WmPot", "lbOvC", "trv4T"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "ContextualLayerInlineTabOrder": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC", "b2zWq", "Nv4jJ", "YGsVX", "trv4T"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "BanzaiStream": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC", "ZU1ro", "trv4T"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "SnappyCompressUtil": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        },
        "KeyEventTypedLogger": {
            "resources": ["lbOvC", "trv4T", "VMKqM"],
            "needsAsync": 1,
            "module": 1
        }
    },
    "resource_map": {
        "ZN6iu": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/yJ\/r\/r98JDkrPdB7.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "lbOvC": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3iQRw4\/y-\/l\/en_US\/5WZyEzO-yKR.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "trv4T": {
            "type": "css",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/y5\/l\/0,cross\/Hams2CQ6T8x.css",
            "permanent": 1,
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "lTQVw": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/yk\/r\/8v3L65OKN6U.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "d25Q1": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/yW\/r\/2Hfsrn8zSCU.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "YGsVX": {
            "type": "css",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/yN\/l\/0,cross\/tw4_CoryHby.css",
            "permanent": 1,
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "eVg16": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3iPWO4\/y7\/l\/en_US\/zUpriHPHyi0.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "CHoRV": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3i3pY4\/yB\/l\/en_US\/QJ9nYHU0qO9.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "vdrq6": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3itvn4\/yT\/l\/en_US\/6_7pVZCnDMo.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "JeUwF": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/y_\/r\/ash8xOAZVK-.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "mzeym": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3i2nZ4\/y4\/l\/en_US\/SE27RbSq37K.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "taIOX": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3if8X4\/yf\/l\/en_US\/I3G_M2Fe60k.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "iaXyh": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3idkl4\/y-\/l\/en_US\/Wcgyvl_N-Xj.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "np5Vl": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/yF\/r\/arfpg0J9xVr.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "I1Wyg": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3i4KP4\/yO\/l\/en_US\/SZb_o9LvjeN.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "Klc20": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/yS\/r\/fPmoZFDHfot.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "+ClWy": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/yF\/r\/rhy6VMHHsHB.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "6Q\/Yd": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3iGqd4\/yn\/l\/en_US\/zcxRQpdn3KC.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "oE4Do": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/yW\/r\/STvuQMoVsgo.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "WmPot": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/yA\/r\/KOciABKx4w7.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "b2zWq": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/yj\/r\/1Q-q4laVvzx.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "Nv4jJ": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3ivjx4\/y7\/l\/en_US\/-wVIYTKb-J1.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "ZU1ro": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/ym\/r\/tnX8h1hMAqX.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "VMKqM": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/yq\/r\/VX_g1H0zcZv.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "eyM74": {
            "type": "css",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/y3\/l\/0,cross\/0uxWhoQ2bKZ.css",
            "permanent": 1,
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "0wVzo": {
            "type": "css",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/y4\/l\/0,cross\/acUhycgW0b0.css",
            "permanent": 1,
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "rwXTv": {
            "type": "css",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/yq\/l\/0,cross\/x7EQi00Ge7H.css",
            "permanent": 1,
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "hAqW4": {
            "type": "css",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/ya\/l\/0,cross\/01llQAe-xml.css",
            "permanent": 1,
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "bTiWO": {
            "type": "css",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3\/ya\/l\/0,cross\/Jxgn8lU3xE2.css",
            "permanent": 1,
            "crossOrigin": 1
        },
        "RIWAf": {
            "type": "js",
            "src": "https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v3ikeI4\/yW\/l\/en_US\/jLnWPpCtWMp.js",
            "crossOrigin": 1
        }
    },
    "ixData": {},
    "gkxData": {
        "AT4kYIk7PhRqUACJJM8qs58t-WNCoM2ZYe35b1xv03xf3OtmC7RfXVIT9hWB6yTOgfA": {
            "result": false,
            "hash": "AT5oUVeShxEj-wBy"
        },
        "AT6ospK-Tdqu5qRhy-TcAU0nIA_ctyO-ghWqmAEjf7bDt3FzGNFL8C4Kn6qbsJrp6oPJYeq6bUEntlvCEgoH4eYQlTJ0DsJar1ZABa0GLxyieQ": {
            "result": false,
            "hash": "AT5lUwvU9ACQ1puA"
        },
        "AT6Afdq0Tt2jEesGOMGnSRKoZIl2eQfQBS7ISXiYFG3RHN4ykkPiZeyWuKALtD0ObEVGeeZuAFKdYpfxlBzUUPkd": {
            "result": false,
            "hash": "AT616ipsS9Q6IRps"
        },
        "AT7IsskI4XB9V3_ZpKFnRxAvs6BVPIgSDbDcq24b8ToUAOY2pCaSzuagN7f_cNx9vGp7vgNftn1_SRfogFUNGS0K": {
            "result": true,
            "hash": "AT5Na-Nz7G8XKMru"
        },
        "AT52sTP_5lkBPKbNz2mUZWsbcEDkBzQg0lQckIsVf32rCwFPbCAUTv2-qAeYwt3QMKM": {
            "result": false,
            "hash": "AT7Pq-Rl8e-_XQMy"
        },
        "AT68bJwSI-83elN-7JSMMH9zt32KbiF6pW-XMlf6NViAJ3CbAk_16Vq8cK1tl1029_ApvFwINR8hmoci3nMKFTDhDCBp1wrvYQbOKq0pCjZpqA": {
            "result": false,
            "hash": "AT7iq4cEmcKTjkfp"
        },
        "AT6DanO60hgFT7juQEF_b5acv5amdrLzodvaFbz5tWF8DGQCmmf0_a7wsRZnn4yNp9kI3S6KXc87dzKSPpUSy11k": {
            "result": false,
            "hash": "AT6MaFQR8z-lSlRA"
        }
    },
    "lid": "6523134272703508330"
}
```

It seems facebook site interprets this response data somehow and renders the freinds names on the page. The data I want is the final rendered web page after scrolling all the way down. But when I use the "requests" module of python or view the page source , most of these HTML content is not present .

how do i proceed around this ?

Comment: you do know that scraping is not allowed on facebook, right? if you want to get the birthdays of friends, the only way is to let them authorize an app with the user_birthday and user_friends permissions.

Comment: ya i know , im not making any production app with this , just for my personal learning and project kind of stuff .

Comment: it does not matter what for you want to use the data, scraping is not allowed. better learn something that´s possible with the graph api instead ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like some sort of a json-like response with the actual html contained in the `__html` field.

Since the actual data is returned in this way, you'll have to do this in a few steps:

1. Load the json data
2. Create a [Selector](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)
3. Extract the data you need from the selector

For example, one way to get the names might be:

```
>>> data = json.loads(response_text[response_text.index('{'):])
>>> sel = Selector(text=data['domops'][0][3]['__html'])
>>> sel.xpath('//a/img/@alt').getall()
['Satish Ven', 'Sheshadri Sharma', 'Aayush Sinha', 'Pranav YS', 'Pankaj Thakur', 'Prajwal Bhadravathi Ravi', 'Sachin R Doddaguni', 'Kajal Chaudhary', 'Usha Shastri', 'Ashish Dwivedi', 'Shreesha Bhat Galimane', 'Chethan Vilas', 'Kshitija Vidya Kallesh', 'Vishesh Umesh Gujjar', 'Santosh Bhat', 'Rahul Kumar', 'Sumanth Sharma', 'Sweekruthi Kashyap', 'Vinayaka Bhat Galimane', 'Pruthvi Kalyan Reddy', 'Kushal Kushu']
```

Do note that scraping facebook is not a great idea, and you'd be better off using their api instead.

Comment: The api needs all those friends to have used my app for that api method to work . So scraping is my only option

Answer (score 0):

A legal solution could be using stalkscan.com functionalities, or another similar fb-crawling site based on official APIs.

Answer (score -2):

Since I'm currently working on a chrome extension to clear the site from all suggested/sponsored content, it seems like a proper workaround for scraping. Keep in mind that facebook is constantly changing its structure and it's not an easy task to find your ways in the DOM tree due to pretty weird tricks.

At the moment you might go into Events -> Birthdays and using proper DOM selectors and logic pick all the dates. Some of them will need to be loaded dynamically after scrolling - this can be handled with a mutationObserver. With this approach you could scroll the birthday page to the bottom once and produce maybe an array with all the name/birthday pairs. So the method is semi-automatic.

There's just too much dynamically loaded content with dynamically changed id/classes + the site keeps changing over time, so going into any details would be futile. If you can make sense of their DOM tree, have a good grasp of DOM manipulation and CSS selectors + a basic knowledge of chrome extension making (it's surprisingly easy) then you can achieve the goal :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).